# ggplot2 stacked bars seem to be separated in many different slices when combined with ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I create the stacked bar chart below but while the code seems to work the bars seem to be separated in slices with a different hover for every slice which is unnecessary and confusing. How can I remove them?

```
Tar2<-structure(list(Site = c("ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", 
"ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", 
"ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", 
"ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", 
"ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", 
"ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", 
"ABC123"), Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A"), Patients = c(46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
c<-ggplot(Tar2, aes(fill=Group, y=Patients, x=Site)) +
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
c<-c+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+labs(title = "Figure 2:Weekly Enrollment by Cohort by Site"
)
ggplotly(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by` and `slice` to get only one row per group:

```r
Tar2 <- structure(list(Site = c(
  "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123",
  "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123",
  "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123",
  "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123",
  "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123",
  "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123",
  "ABC123"
), Group = c(
  "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A",
  "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
  "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B",
  "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A"
), Patients = c(
  46L, 46L, 46L, 46L,
  46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L,
  46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L,
  46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -40L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)

c <-
  Tar2 %>%
  group_by(Group, Patients, Site) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = Group, y = Patients, x = Site)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(title = "Figure 2:Weekly Enrollment by Cohort by Site")
c
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>